# Unique Customers in last 7 days in SSAS Tabular DAX

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I've been trying to get my head around how to do this with DAX, and I'm not having much success. The following is essentially the formula I am looking for, with one deficiency (below):

```
Last 7 Days Unique Customer IDs:=CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[CustomerID]),
        FILTER(OrderDate, OrderDate[RelativeDateOffset] >= -7)
)
```

That works in a pivot table in excel, but once a timeline (or any date filter) is introduced the measure then becomes contextual and is no longer the correct number. I've tried adding ALL(OrderDate) into the mix to clear the filters on OrderDate, but then the number is entirely incorrect.

```
Last 7 Days Unique Customer IDs:=CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[CustomerID]),
        FILTER(ALL(OrderDate), OrderDate[RelativeDateOffset] >= -7)
)
```